# Rails + Simple Form - Create a form with two buttons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to create a form with two buttons. One would be the `submit` button, but I would also like to have a second button that would allow creating a required element of the form if it does not exist already.

Something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @class do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.association :teacher %>
  <%= f.button :new_teacher, new_teacher_path, "Add a Teacher" %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

What I want to happen when the `:new_teacher` button is clicked is for the new teacher view to open, the user would then fill that out, submit it, and return to creating the class. Is there a sane way to do this?

This is mostly a design issue, it feels like the button should be "within" the form, so that if the user runs into a missing item while filling out the form s/he can easily create it.

Comment: class `Teacher` belongs to class `Class`?

Comment: The other way around, class `Class` belongs_to class `Teacher`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that I've found is to use the `link_to` helper with the link styled as a button. Like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Add a Teacher', new_teacher_path, :class => 'button' %>
```

I tried using `button_to` instead of `link_to` and it appears that Simple Form is clever enough to notice that and assume that the button should operate within the context of the form, so I don't get the path I want.

Answer (score -1):

It's not exactly related to this, but it might help someone who is looking for an option on how to send a request with a button, including parameters. So let's break this down for clarity. We'll cover the default request type and how to modify it in Rails, both before and after version 5

Certainly, here's a simplified breakdown for **before** and **after** Rails 5:

**Before Rails 5:**

- **Default Request Type**: Forms and buttons send HTML requests.
- **For JSON Requests**: Add `remote: true` to your forms and buttons to send JSON requests using Ajax.

**After Rails 5:**

- **Default Request Type**: Forms and buttons send JSON requests using JavaScript (Ajax) by default.
- **For HTML Requests**: Use `local: true` in your forms and buttons to switch back to sending HTML requests.

#### Example Before Rails 5

**Default Request Type**: HTML

**Sending HTML Request**:

1. **Form**:

   ```
   <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
     <!-- form elements here -->
   <% end %>
   ```

   Default behavior, submits as an HTML request.
2. **Button**:

   ```
   <%= button_to "View Detail", movie_detail_path, method: :get, params: { movie_id: movie['id'] } %>
   ```

   Submits as an HTML request.
3. **Link**:

   ```
   <%= link_to "View Details", movie_detail_path(movie_id: movie['id']) %>
   ```

   Behaves as a standard link (HTML GET request).

**Sending JSON Request**:

1. **Form**:

   ```
   <%= form_for @post, remote: true do |f| %>
     <!-- form elements here -->
   <% end %>
   ```

   Uses Ajax for submission (can handle JSON response).
2. **Button**:

   ```
   <%= button_to "View Detail", movie_detail_path(format: :json), method: :get, params: { movie_id: movie['id'] }, remote: true %>
   ```

   Specifies JSON format and uses Ajax.
3. **Link**:

   ```
   <%= link_to "View Details", movie_detail_path(movie_id: movie['id'], format: :json), remote: true %>
   ```

   Specifies JSON format and makes an Ajax request.

#### After Rails 5

**Default Request Type**: JavaScript (Ajax)

**Sending HTML Request**:

1. **Form**:

   ```
   <%= form_with model: @post, local: true do |f| %>
     <!-- form elements here -->
   <% end %>
   ```

   Specifies `local: true` to submit as HTML.
2. **Button**:

   ```
   <%= button_to "View Detail", movie_detail_path, method: :get, params: { movie_id: movie['id'] }, local: true %>
   ```

   Specifies `local: true` for HTML submission.
3. **Link**:

   ```
   <%= link_to "View Details", movie_detail_path(movie_id: movie['id']) %>
   ```

   Behaves as a standard link (HTML GET request).

**Sending JSON Request**:

1. **Form**:

   ```
   <%= form_with model: @post do |f| %>
     <!-- form elements here -->
   <% end %>
   ```

   Default behavior, submits as an Ajax request (can handle JSON response).
2. **Button**:

   ```
   <%= button_to "View Detail", movie_detail_path(format: :json), method: :get, params: { movie_id: movie['id'] } %>
   ```

   Specifies JSON format, default Ajax submission.
3. **Link**:

   ```
   <%= link_to "View Details", movie_detail_path(movie_id: movie['id'], format: :json) %>
   ```

   Specifies JSON format, standard link behavior.